# How to solve overloaded method value register with alternatives, UDF Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

i am trying to take the last tocken of a full filepath and my code look likes

```
val testUdf = spark.udf.register("get_filename", (fullpath: String) => {
  val lastIndex = fullpath.lastIndexOf("/")
  fullpath.substring(lastIndex, fullpath.length - 1)}, DataTypes.StringType)
```

and i get an error:

```
Error:(39, 29) overloaded method value register with alternatives:
  (name: String,f: org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF22[_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _],returnType: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType)Unit <and> ......
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no variant of `register` method that takes Scala closure and `DataType` (there exist such variants of `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf`, designed for Java interoperability).

If you use closures with register, function should return object that can be mapped to SQL types by reflection. In your case it is satisfied so just omit data type:

```
val testUdf = spark.udf.register("get_filename", (fullpath: String) => {
 val lastIndex = fullpath.lastIndexOf("/")
 fullpath.substring(lastIndex, fullpath.length - 1)}
)
```